# "Now Playing" icon will not go away in Monterey

Tags: menu-bar, monterey

This image says it all. As you can see, I have turned off Now Playing's "Show in Menu Bar", but it's still there.

Yes, I have closed and opened the control panel, clicked various controls in an attempt to "save" the setting, and so forth. I have also tried command-dragging the icon out, which works for about 0.1 seconds and then it reappears at a new location (the one seen here, it was previously further right).

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know what this icon was for, Google'd and found your thread, have clicked to turn it off and it's still there to same issue here. When I click it, it shows me a safari tab which isn't even open any more and the mail app with no specific email selected.